# How to get the "overall" counter of an object in a group in a Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm using Django's [regroup template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/) to group a series of objects. Let's say these are the objects:

```
cities = [
    {"name": "Mumbai", "population": "19,000,000", "country": "India"},
    {"name": "Calcutta", "population": "15,000,000", "country": "India"},
    {"name": "New York", "population": "20,000,000", "country": "USA"},
    {"name": "Chicago", "population": "7,000,000", "country": "USA"},
    {"name": "Tokyo", "population": "33,000,000", "country": "Japan"},
]
```

In my template, I'm grouping them like this:

```
{% regroup cities by country as country_list %}

<ul>
{% for country in country_list %}
    <li>{{ country.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for city in country.list %}
          <li>{{ city.name }}: {{ city.population }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Which results in

```
India
    Mumbai: 19,000,000
    Calcutta: 15,000,000
USA
    New York: 20,000,000
    Chicago: 7,000,000
Japan
    Tokyo: 33,000,000
```

I would like to show an "overall" index for each object, so that it looks like this:

```
India
    1: Mumbai: 19,000,000
    2: Calcutta: 15,000,000
USA
    3: New York: 20,000,000
    4: Chicago: 7,000,000
Japan
    5: Tokyo: 33,000,000
```

I'm not asking for an HTML solution; my use case is a series of grouped questions and I would like to add a question counter.

Is there a way to do this in the template, or should I write the necessary code in my view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to add the index in your view, Django intentionally restricts the capabilities within its template language to discourage the inclusion of extensive logic directly within templates. I recommend addressing this by following the suggested approach:

```py
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render

def your_view(request):
    cities = [
        {"name": "Mumbai", "population": "19,000,000", "country": "India"},
        {"name": "Calcutta", "population": "15,000,000", "country": "India"},
        {"name": "New York", "population": "20,000,000", "country": "USA"},
        {"name": "Chicago", "population": "7,000,000", "country": "USA"},
        {"name": "Tokyo", "population": "33,000,000", "country": "Japan"},
    ]

    # Add an index to each city
    for index, city in enumerate(cities, start=1):
        city['index'] = index

    return render(request, 'your_template.html', {'cities': cities})
```

Then in your template, you can use the index attribute:

```html
{% regroup cities by country as country_list %}

<ul>
    {% for country in country_list %}
        <li>{{ country.grouper }}
        <ul>
            {% for city in country.list %}
                {% with counter=counter|add:1 %}
                 <li>{{ city.index }}: {{ city.name }}: {{ city.population }}</li>
                {% endwith %}
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: No, it doesn't unfortunately: `forloop.parentloop.counter` gives me the index of `country` in `country_list`. (I grabbed a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/g3MI0v6))

Comment: Oh sorry man, Django intentionally restricts the capabilities within its template language to discourage the inclusion of extensive logic directly within templates. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Yeah, thought so -- no problem, now I know I don't have to fret over trying to get this done in the template :)